# Auto layout в IOS

Tags: ios, autolayout

Привет, есть небольшая проблема с auto layout. У меня расположено много UI элементов на одной линии, которые влезают на экран (any, any). Мне нужно, чтобы UI элементы, которые не влезают на экран сдвигались вниз. Можно ли это сделать при помощи auto layout? У UI элементов фиксированная ширина и высота.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать добавить на экран `UICollectionView` и сложить в него все элементы. Тогда что не влезет будет на второй строке, третьей и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Для таких вещей используют сайзклассы

Answer (score 0):

Есть как минимум 2 решения:

1. UIStackView (если таргет иос9+) или [OAStackView](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView) для более ранних версий, к примеру
2. UICollectionView с правильно настроенным layout (либо подобрать параметры в flow layout, либо сделать свой сабкласс)

Чистым autolayout тут не обойтись точно.